# JS: What is the difference of adding click event on the body and adding click event on document

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript, I want to listen for click events on the whole HTML page.

What is the difference of adding it on body element, and
adding it on document element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<body>` element does not cover the whole page, then clicking on parts outside of it will not trigger any click listeners. Add the event listener on the document to handle click events on any part of the page.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('body click'));
document.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('document click'))
```

```html
Some content... (try clicking under here)
```

The effect is more clear if you add a border around the body.